# Is Timer object isn't being collected by garbage collector?

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I try to figure the following code:

```
    package com.company;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Timer T = new Timer();
        TimerTask Birthday = new TimerTask(){
            int i = 5;
            @Override
            public void run(){
                if(i>0){
                    System.out.println(i);
                    i--;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Happy Birthday John Doe");
                    T.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        date.set(2021, Calendar.OCTOBER, 30,23, 59, 54);
       T.scheduleAtFixedRate(Birthday, date.getTime(), 1000);
    }
}
```

I have difficult to understand how the  following line works:

> T.cancel();

Isn't T (Timer) was collected by garbage collector when the **main** method ends?
After all the **run** method of **TimerTask** class continue to run after **main** thread was close and therefore i assume that **Timer T** object was collected by garbage collector and when running the row **T.cancel()** a run time exception should appear.
Can someone explain me what is wrong with the way i see the things?

Comment: `i assume that Timer T object was collected by garbage collector and when running the row T.cancel() a run time exception should appear.` What? Why? The garbage collector collects objects which are unreachable. The timer _clearly_ isn't.

Comment: @tkausl, by who the object is reachable? Who holds reference to the object?

Answer (score 2):

The Timer's thread has a reference to the `T` instance and therefore it will not be garbage collected.  An object cannot be garbage collected until it is unreachable to every live thread.

Comment: T reference can be used although the function he is declared in was closed?

Comment: Yes. The reference of an object can be passed on to other methods/threads, as long as the new scope is being invoked from the current scope.